# Ruby 2.1 fails to install due to OpenSSL error

Tags: ruby, openssl, debian

I can not seem to install Ruby 2.1 on Debian Wheezy. Every time, it throws an OpenSSL error. Here are my installation steps:

```
apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev curl git-core python-software-properties openssl

cd /root
wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.0.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ruby-2.1.0.tar.gz
cd /root/ruby-2.1.0
./configure prefix=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.0
make && make install
```

& the resulting error:

```
ossl_ssl.c:2232:5: error: ‘SSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ossl_ssl.c:2232:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[2]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/ruby-2.1.0/ext/openssl'
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/ruby-2.1.0'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

This error started affecting my installation today. I've been trying to resolve the issue all afternoon with no success. Anyone know what's going on? Why might it occur today?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are attempting to install Ruby 2.1, but this issue is solved in Ruby 2.1.1 & higher [as explained here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9301).

> **SSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING** has been removed from latest snapshot
>   of OpenSSL 1.0.1.  [Fixes GH-488]

Further [details here](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v2_1_1/ChangeLog) in the official Ruby repository:

> Mon Jan 27 16:45:34 2014  Yamashita Yuu
>
> - ext/openssl/ossl_ssl.c (Init_ossl_ssl): Declare a constant
>     **OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING** only if the macro is defined.  The
>     **SSL_OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING** has been removed from latest
>     snapshot of OpenSSL 1.0.1.  [Fixes GH-488]

Comment: Cheers, mate. Exactly what I needed to know.